# Select values between 2 values set with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I'm working with moment.js in Angular 5.

I have and array like this:

```js
public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [  "2018/26/02 10:01:00", "2018/26/02 10:02:00", "2018/26/02 10:03:00", "2018/26/02 10:04:00", "2018/26/02 10:05:00", "2018/26/02 10:06:00", "2018/26/02 10:07:00", "2018/26/02 10:08:00", "2018/26/02 10:09:00", "2018/26/02 10:10:00", "2018/26/02 10:11:00", "2018/26/02 10:12:00","2018/26/02 10:13:00", "2018/26/02 10:14:00", "2018/26/02 10:15:00" ];
```

and I have `timeStart;` and `timeEnd;`. I report only first, I initialize both in the same way

```js
let timeStart = moment();
timeStart.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
timeStart.year(2018);
timeStart.month(2);
timeStart.date(26);
timeStart.hour(10);
timeStart.minute(10);
timeStart.second(0);
```

for `timeEnd` I use `timeStart.hour(10); timeStart.minute(13);`

Now I have to implement this cycle:

```js
for( let i = 0; i < this.lineChartLabels.length; i++ ){
  if (moment(this.lineChartsLabels[i]).isBetween(timeStart, timeEnd) ) {
    console.log ( 'true' );
  }
  else {
    console.log ( 'false' );
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you know how can I resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

- Since `lineChartLabels` values are not in format recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822), so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) passing format as second parameter (`'YYYY/DD/MM HH:mm:ss'` in your case)
- JavaScript months are 0 indexed, so [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/):

  > Gets or sets the month.
  >
  > Accepts numbers from 0 to 11. If the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to the year.

  Your `timeStart` and `timeEnd` represent the 26th of March

Here a live sample:

```js
const lineChartLabels = [  "2018/26/02 10:01:00", "2018/26/02 10:02:00", "2018/26/02 10:03:00", "2018/26/02 10:04:00", "2018/26/02 10:05:00", "2018/26/02 10:06:00", "2018/26/02 10:07:00", "2018/26/02 10:08:00", "2018/26/02 10:09:00", "2018/26/02 10:10:00", "2018/26/02 10:11:00", "2018/26/02 10:12:00","2018/26/02 10:13:00", "2018/26/02 10:14:00", "2018/26/02 10:15:00" ];

let timeStart = moment();
timeStart.year(2018);
timeStart.month(2-1); // Months are 0 index, 2 stands for March
timeStart.date(26);
timeStart.hour(10);
timeStart.minute(10);
timeStart.second(0);

let timeEnd = moment(timeStart).hour(10).minute(13);

console.log(timeStart.format());
console.log(timeEnd.format());

for( let i = 0; i < lineChartLabels.length; i++ ){
  if (moment(lineChartLabels[i], 'YYYY/DD/MM HH:mm:ss').isBetween(timeStart, timeEnd) ) {
    console.log ( 'true' );
  }
  else {
    console.log ( 'false' );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, thank you very much for your reply! I also noticed the error that sent me off the road ... I reversed MM and DD
thanks again!

Comment: I also leave here the link with [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/isolate-interval-on-from-time-picker)